# MongoDB shell mongoimport not importing document from json file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone help me figure out what the problem is with this cos i have been trying to get it work but all efforts avail abortive

```
mongoimport --db test  --collection products --drop --file"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\scripts\products.json"
```

running the above on my shell keeps given me the below error

```
2018-01-13T19:55:55.019+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:14
```

======================Update=========================

```js
{ "_id" : "ac3", "name" : "AC3 Phone", "brand" : "ACME", "type" : "phone", "price" : 200, "warranty_years" : 1, "available" : true }
{ "_id" : "ac7", "name" : "AC7 Phone", "brand" : "ACME", "type" : "phone", "price" : 320, "warranty_years" : 1, "available" : false }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bf9" }, "name" : "AC3 Series Charger", "type" : [ "accessory", "charger" ], "price" : 19, "warranty_years" : 0.25, "for" : [ "ac3", "ac7", "ac9" ] }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfa" }, "name" : "AC3 Case Green", "type" : [ "accessory", "case" ], "color" : "green", "price" : 12, "warranty_years" : 0 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfb" }, "name" : "Phone Extended Warranty", "type" : "warranty", "price" : 38, "warranty_years" : 2, "for" : [ "ac3", "ac7", "ac9", "qp7", "qp8", "qp9" ] }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfc" }, "name" : "AC3 Case Black", "type" : [ "accessory", "case" ], "color" : "black", "price" : 12.5, "warranty_years" : 0.25, "available" : false, "for" : "ac3" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfd" }, "name" : "AC3 Case Red", "type" : [ "accessory", "case" ], "color" : "red", "price" : 12, "warranty_years" : 0.25, "available" : true, "for" : "ac3" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bfe" }, "name" : "Phone Service Basic Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 40, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 400, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "units" : "gigabytes", "n" : 20, "over_rate" : 1 }, "sms" : { "units" : "texts sent", "n" : 100, "over_rate" : 0.001 } }, "term_years" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15bff" }, "name" : "Phone Service Core Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 60, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 1000, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 }, "sms" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 } }, "term_years" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15c00" }, "name" : "Phone Service Family Plan", "type" : "service", "monthly_price" : 90, "limits" : { "voice" : { "units" : "minutes", "n" : 1200, "over_rate" : 0.05 }, "data" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 }, "sms" : { "n" : "unlimited", "over_rate" : 0 } }, "sales_tax" : true, "term_years" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "507d95d5719dbef170f15c01" }, "name" : "Cable TV Basic Service Package", "type" : "tv", "monthly_price" : 50, "term_years" : 2, "cancel_penalty" : 25, "sales_tax" : true, "additional_tarriffs" : [ { "kind" : "federal tarriff", "amount" : { "percent_of_service" : 0.06 } }, { "kind" : "misc tarriff", "amount" : 2.25 } ] }
```

Comment: Is your JSON file well formed? Can you post few lines of the JSON file ?

Comment: cant reproduce the issue. mongoimport runs fine after from adding missing space between file and file path.

Comment: Based on the error message it appears that you are trying to run `mongoimport` inside the `mongo` shell. Utilities like `mongoimport` need to be run from a command shell (eg `cmd.exe` on Windows or `bash` on Unix/Linux environments).

Comment: the above command was on mongo shell@Stennie and @veeram i did make a mistake posting it here like that but on the shell i did observe the space but still not running.

Comment: You **can't** run mongoimport command from  mongo shell. Come out of mongo shell and run mongoimport from bin folder.

Comment: Thanks bro. i did run cmd from the download and the it worked